# merge two file pdf into one file override?

Tags: php, pdf

I have two file pdf, 1st file containing the chart and 2nd file contains information chart.
How to pair the two files back together, right with the position of each page.
I using php,apache2,ubuntu.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is very ambiguous but going by what I understand, I think you would first need to extract the contents of both pdf's and then map them according to their values from pdf1 to pdf2. For this you can use [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) OCR to extract the data and then by writing your code you can try and match them according to their position on page.

Maybe if you just elaborate your question a bit I could help you more.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm using pdftk merge two file pdf together.